# Dynamically load stylesheets/scripts based on pages need? (Old UI framework for old pages, new UI framework for new pages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

Let's say I have a base HTML page (index.html) that loads the currently used front-end framework. I would like to be able to simultaneously use the current front-end framework for the pages that are already built and use a new front-end framework for pages that will be built.

Let us assume these front-end frameworks interfere with one another and there is a lot of styles in the old framework that clashes with the new framework so we need to use one or the other.

Example:

(Bootstrap is not the old framework, this is merely for an example)

oldpage.html includes:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

newpage.html should only include:

(Semantic-UI is the new framework I am using)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

How might I dynamically load between these two in index.html? When you go to newpage.html you should only see the Semantic-UI framework loaded and not the old framework (Boostrap). In the new pages you should see only Bootstrap loaded and not the new framework (Semantic-UI).

Comment: If these two pages are different, why would you try to have the two framework working together? For the javascript it's easy (simply use a javascript module loader like requirejs or systemjs), but for the css you'll always have the latest css rule in top of the previous css rule, the look will be ugly when the css classes match.

Comment: For the CSS, there is `<link rel="alternate stylesheet" ...>`, which allows users to go back and forth between styles from the browser (or do more, if you manipulate the `<link>` w/ JavaScript), but without knowing more about the use case (internal testing? end user preference? etc.), it's hard to give further feedback.

Comment: To be more specific, I am working with a project that uses asp web forms and the mvc model. There is currently a large mix of general scripts and stylesheets that are being used for each page in the entire solution. Making this happen with web forms was simple, a mix of utilizing a boolean and different master pages allowed this to work out easier. Transitioning in mvc is the difficulty. There is a base page where each page gets its sources from in the entire solution. I want only the new pages to be able to use semantic-ui and not the old scripts/styles.

Comment: Are you using layout pages with MVC? or does everything go through master pages?

Comment: It is a combination. Master pages are used for the projects utilizing web forms and layouts are utilized for projects using MVC. This solution has 100+ projects in.